# How can I refer to the ssl keystore located inside a project?

Tags: java, spring-boot, cloud-foundry

I have the following code which sets the ssl keystore from the keystore located in the project under the resources folder:

```
String certpath = getClass().getResource("/appcertkeystore").getPath();
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", certpath);
```

The code above works locally but not in the pcf cloud. In PCF, the path it is trying to access is:

```
/home/vcap/app/.java-buildpack/tomcat/webapps/pad/WEB-INF/classes/appcertkeystore
```

Is there a workaround to make it work in the pcf cloud?

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to provide the absolute path of your truststore - best is to externalize it as an environment variable by setting JAVA_OPTS to include -Djavax.net.ssl.Truststore and point that to the truststore you bundle with the app. Please be advised that this completely overrides the default truststore, so you need to add all the usual defaults plus your custom trusted certs. example given below:

   `cf set-env <app> JAVA_OPTS '-Djavax.net.ssl.TrustStore=classpath:resources/certs/truststore'`
2. Another option - You can add a .profile script that would call keytool and imports custom cert that is packaged with the application into default keystore. Make sure you add the script in the root of the WAR or JAR file that you generate.
   .profile script would look like this:

   `#!/bin/bash`
   `$HOME/.java-buildpack/open_jdk_jre/bin/keytool -keystore $HOME/.java-  buildpack/open_jdk_jre/lib/security/cacerts -storepass changeit -importcert -  noprompt -alias MyCert -file $HOME/WEB-INF/ssl/MyCert.crt`